# Working on FFmpeg with VC++ 2010

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use FFmpeg in VC++ 2010 so that i can use ffmpeg in to my VC++ Code , i first Install the FFmpeg in to machine by Help provided by youtube video "FFMPEG build for windows"

while building the sample code provided by ffmpeg (muxing.c) i got following error's

1. error C1189: #error : missing-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS /#define _STDC_FORMAT_MACROS

2 IntelliSense: #error directive: missing -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS / #define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS 
c:\users----\ffmpeg\ffmpeg\include\libavutil\timestamp.h

how to resolve this error

i have already done following

1.Project-->properties-->Configuration Properties--> VC++ Directories --> include dir {add all the header files from ffmpeg folder here}

2. in Configuration Properties--> C/C++-->Command Line-->Additional Options --> add {-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS }

any help would be highly appreciate

Thanks

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Thanx for your time.

Problem is sorted out by putting header files extern to main() body .

```
1. #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS


2. extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
av_register_all();
return 0;
}
```

Regards

kaushal